# MSMQ Instance in memory

Tags: c#, performance, msmq, memory-mapped-files, devops

I'm trying to fine tune the performance of my acceptance test suite. I've discovered that most of the performance bottleneck is due to MSMQ storage files being on a slow IO VM Disk. I've tried moving the MSMQ Storage folder to a RAM DISK, but for some bizarre reason, MSMQ throws an I/O device error when you try to create a private queue using "Computer Management" on Windows Server 2012 R2. It works just fine in Windows 7,8 and 10. So I really dont know what the issue is with RAM DISKS, MSMQ and Windows 2012 R2.

As an alternative, I was thinking instead of worrying about storing my MSMQ files on a fast disk or even a RAM DISK, why not just create a new in-memory MSMQ Component instance, and then have all my queues in memory.

Note that this code will only be used to improve performance of my acceptance nunit test suite. ATM, it takes 2.5 hours to complete (4000 tests, using NServiceBUS, MSMQ and RavenDB). I've managed to move all components to RAMDISK and this has decreased runtime by almost 40%. Thats when I test it on Windows 7,8,10 using MSMQ on the RAMDISK. When doing the same in Windows 2012 R2, I can move everything to the RAM Disk and it works fine, but I cant get MSMQ to work on the RAMDISK.And strangely enough, I lost all performance gains when MSMQ is not on the RAMDISK. I guess the I/O bottleneck is really bad!

Any advice?

Comment: Buy a SSD! What are you waiting for? ;)

Comment: MSMQ queues are *NOT* persistent by default. The default option is memory storage.  You have to explicitly make them persistent when you create them. Don't

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: It's not that easy. I work for a large company, we use AWS server instances to host our environments. Team City is hosted on a AWS VM, and as mentioned, the test suite runs 2.5 hours. The disks on this VM reads/write at 150MB/s, with a ram disk on this server, I get 5000MB/s

Comment: @FaNIX But you said that you can't move MSMQ to RamDisk. So, you can get 500-600MB/s read/write speed with a cheap SSD. If you can't choose your disk tech for this particular case, maybe it's time to rent a dedicated test server where you can install a SDD disk and solve this problem

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: you are going off topic. If it was that easy I would have done it, trust me. As  I said, I work for a big company, the process to get these things approved and purchased is a nightmare.

Comment: @FaNIX Sadly, I'll need to say *good luck with this*. The problem is how big a company is, but the problem is how blocking can be people on company's hierarchy :(

Comment: "MSMQ queues are NOT persistent by default. The default option is memory storage. You have to explicitly make them persistent when you create them. Don't". This is incorrect. Queues don't exist as things - messages do. Messages can be set to be persistent (that is, recoverable) or not. Express messages can be recoverable or not; transactional messages are always recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The ramdisk driver I was using doesn't support Win 2012 R2 with storage stores. It works fine for everything else, but for some reason MSMQ didn't like it. So I tried another ramdisk driver (Primo Ramdisk Server Edition), and msmq finally worked.

I used the following to move the location of the MSMQ files:

```
$MSMQStoragePath = "P:\MSMQ"
$MessageFilePath = "$MSMQStoragePath\MessageFiles"
$XactLogsPath = "$MSMQStoragePath\XactLogs"
$StoragePath = "$MSMQStoragePath\Storage"
Write-Host "$MessageFilePath - $XactLogsPath - $StoragePath"
$MSMQPath = Split-Path -Path $MessageFilePath -Parent
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$MessageFilePath\LQS" -Verbose
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $XactLogsPath -Verbose
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $StoragePath -Verbose
icacls $MSMQPath /grant "NT SERVICE\MSMQ:(OI)(F)"
icacls "$MessageFilePath\LQS" /grant "NT SERVICE\MSMQ:(OI)(F)"
Set-MsmqQueueManager -MessageQuota 10485760 -JournalQuota 10485760 -MsgStore $MessageFilePath -MsgLogStore $XactLogsPath -TransactionLogStore $StoragePath -Verbose -Confirm:$false
Start-Service MSMQ -Verbose
```

Running my test suite now takes 67min, down from 150min!